# Adding " li " items to select as options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/), and when I add values to it, I get a `ul` like this

```
<ul id="mytags" class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable">
<span class="tagit-label">Android</span>
<a class="tagit-close"><span class="text-icon">×</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a>
</li>
<li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable">
<span class="tagit-label">Java</span>
<a class="tagit-close"><span class="text-icon">×</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a>
</li>
<li class="tagit-new"><input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to populate a select element from it

```
$("#tagQuery").tagit({
    availableTags: ["c++", "java", "play", "scala", "ruby", "python", "c"],
    afterTagAdded : function(event, ui) {
             var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = this.value;
                option.text = this.name;
                option.selected = 'selected';
                select.appendChild(option);
        },
        afterTagRemoved : function(event, ui) {
            select.removeChild(select.querySelector('[value="'+this.value+'"]'));
        }
});
```

but the above code does not work as expected.

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LjomqhbL/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get tag name use `ui.tagLabel`.
2. select variable is not defined in your code. initialize select variable as `var select = document.querySelector("select");` or `var select = document.querySelector("select[name='tags']");`

Try: https://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/LjomqhbL/19/

**Snippet:**

```js
var select = document.querySelector("select");
$("#tagQuery").tagit({
    availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"],
    afterTagAdded : function(event, ui) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
       console.log(ui);
       option.value = ui.tagLabel;
       option.text =  ui.tagLabel;
       option.selected = 'selected';
       select.appendChild(option);
  },
  afterTagRemoved : function(event, ui) {
   select.removeChild(select.querySelector('[value="'+ui.tagLabel+'"]'));
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/aehlke/tag-it/master/css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/aehlke/tag-it/master/js/tag-it.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="tagQuery" type="text" placeholder="tags" class="input-field"/><br> 
   <ul id="mytags"></ul><br><br>  
      
      <select name="tags" path="tags">
   </select>
```

**Edit:**

add position of tag as value i.e `<option value="2">Java</option>` instead of `<option value="Java">Java</option>`

`this.value` return the tag string with seperator comma. eg java,javascript. So spilt the string and get the length of array use as option value.

```
var arr=this.value.split(',');
option.value = arr.length;
```

Comment: OK this adds values as `options` to `select`, can you do a favor me? that is how can I get and add position of tag as value __i.e `<option value="2">Java</option>` instead of `<option value="Java">Java</option>` please...__

Comment: I think that will be better to ask a new question regarding to that issue, but the mentioned issue is resolved thanks a __ton__ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following using `append()` and `remove()`. To add index as value declare `availableTags` as a global variable. Hope this will help you.

```
var availableTags= ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"];

$("#tagQuery").tagit({
    availableTags: availableTags,
    afterTagAdded : function(event, ui) {
        var arr=this.value.split(',');
        var text = arr[arr.length - 1];
        var index = availableTags.indexOf(text)+1;

       $('select[name=tags]').append('<option selected value='+index+'>'+text+'</option>');
    },
    afterTagRemoved : function(event, ui) {
        $('select[name=tags] option[value='+ui.tagLabel+']').remove();
    }
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/LjomqhbL/23/)

Comment: OK this adds values as `options` to `select`, can you do a favor me? that is how can I get and add position of tag as value __i.e `<option value="2">Java</option>` instead of `<option value="Java">Java</option>` please...__

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find... You want the last selection to be your selected value. So I just changed the Script a bit.

```
$("#tagQuery").tagit({
      availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"],
      afterTagAdded : function(event, ui) {
          $option = $("<option>");
          $option.attr("value", ui.tagLabel);
          $option.text(ui.tagLabel);
          $("select[name='tags']").append($option);
          $("select[name='tags']").val(ui.tagLabel);
      },
      afterTagRemoved : function(event, ui) {
            $("select[name='tags']").find('option[value="'+ui.tagLabel+'"]').remove();
      }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LjomqhbL/21/)

Comment: OK this adds values as `options` to `select`, can you do a favor me? that is how can I get and add position of tag as value __i.e `<option value="2">Java</option>` instead of `<option value="Java">Java</option>` please...__

Comment: Okay... You want the order of the Tags with the Option values. Or the index of the Original array: `availableTags`?

Comment: Here you go... 1. Main Position (Index + 1) of the tags in availableTags array https://jsfiddle.net/LjomqhbL/22/